# figure, errors '\undefined control sequence - \ltx@Ifundefined{....'

Tags: errors

Please help me tell why the following code is not correct?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{lls.eps}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{AIC.eps}\\
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{BIC.eps}\\
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

or other code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \label{figur}\caption{equation...}
  \begin{tabular}{cp{2cm}c}
    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{1.eps}& & \includegraphics[width=60mm]{lls.eps}\\
    & & &\\
    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{2.eps}& & \includegraphics[width=60mm]{AIC.eps}\\
    & & &\\
    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{3.eps}& & \includegraphics[width=60mm]{BIC.eps}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your errors: your code compiles w/o warnings with LaTeX on my computer.

Comment: tell us your error message and by the way: `\label{figur}\caption{equation...}` use it the other way round, first the `caption` and then the `label`. Otherwise you'll get wrong references.

Comment: Are you using `latex` oder `pdflatex`?

Comment: Did you find it out? Do you have an example which reproduces the error? Did installing the `oberdiek` bundle help?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is compilable, so there's no problem visible in those two examples.

Regarding the error message in the title: I recommend to install or to update the [`oberdiek bundle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek). This bundle contains a package [`ltxcmds.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds), which defines the macro `\ltx@IfUndefined`. I guess a package you're using relies on a current version of `oberdiek` and `ltxcmds`, respectively.